# ¿Cómo obtener dimensiones de la pantalla en Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla de un dispositivo Android, estoy intentando con este código:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // obsoleto (deprecated)
int height = display.getHeight();  // obsoleto (deprecated)
```

El cual se encuentra obsoleto (deprecado), ¿Cual sería la actual forma correcta de obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla del dispositivo?

Comment: Hector, acabo de ver tu respuesta, te pongo un ejemplo del método que utilizo para obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla correctamente para todas las APIs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels; // ancho absoluto en pixels 
int height = metrics.heightPixels; // alto absoluto en pixels
```

Nota: Esta forma esta soportada desde API Level 1

Comment: `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);` no lo asignas a nada? o que hace esa linea?

Comment: getMetrics(metrics) _llena_ la variable metrics con los datos, por eso se crea un objeto DisplayMetrics con anterioridad.

Answer (score 3):

Lo correcto para **obtener las dimensiones de pantalla en Android y pueda funcionar correctamente en todas las APIs** sería :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {  // > API 12
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
    } else {
        width   = display.getWidth();
        height  = display.getHeight();
    }
```

Otra forma sería utilizando:

> [**DisplayMetrics**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) Una estructura que describe la información general
>   sobre una pantalla, tal como su tamaño, densidad y escala de fuentes.

Para acceder a los miembros `DisplayMetrics`, inicializar un objeto como éste:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

- Otra forma sería:

  ```
  int widthPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
  int heightPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
  ```

Comment: Exelente aporte Jorge, siempre que busco cosas tus comentarios de exelencia

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Aunque la forma antigua continúa funcionando correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar también usando el método getResources de manera automática sin importar nuevas clases

```
int width = this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp;

int height = this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Soy nuevo en el foro y por Gracias a todos por sus múltiples aportes respecto a este tema veo q todo lo dicho funciona bien pero no en el caso que estoy desarrollando un componente Personalizado extiende  de LinearLayout o de cualquier ViewGroup si quires tomar las dimensiones de pantalla desde una clase 
 como la que comento  (entonces ojo q no estoy en la Activity si no en una clase extendida de LinearLayout ) Solo me ha funcionado esto:

```
    int width = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Leonardo, es bueno tenerte aquí, en realidad no es un foro es mucho mejor!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que entiendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio,  revisa [ask] y [answer] que te brinda información importante para colaborar con el sitio. Realiza una pregunta!, por lo pronto te recomiendo eliminar esta publicación. Saludos y suerte!