# ¿Si hay espacio en la action bar por que no muestra los icono que tienen showAsAction="ifRoom"?

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbar

hola tengo un menu en la action bar que es el siguiente:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="Buscar"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorita"
        android:title="Favorito"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_no_favorito"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nota"
        android:title="Nota"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mode_comment_white_18dp"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/editar"
        android:title="Editar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit_white"
        appcompat:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/enviar"
        android:title="Enviar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_18dp"
        appcompat:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/donde_estoy"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_place_white_18dp"
        android:title="¿Dónde estoy?"
        appcompat:showAsAction="ifRoom" />



</menu>
```

pero entonces cundo tengo el telefono hoirizontal no muestra los iconos que tiene la propiedad showAsAction="ifRoom".....miren la foto: ven como hay espacio y aun asi hay tres menus ocultos...

[image: ven como hay espacio y aun asi hay tres menus ocultos]

Comment: creo que se puede alterar, para forzar que los items se muestren

Comment: Como comenta WebServeis otra opción es que puedes realizar por ejemplo tu propio ToolBar y agregar los elementos que necesites. @Felix A Marrero Pentón

Answer (score 2):

Son varios elementos que tienes marcados como "ifRoom" ademas de los "always", recuerda que si no hay espacio para todos los marcados como "ifRoom" no los va a mostrar, en este caso también tienes un titulo que no tiene texto pero que tiene un espacio el cual debes contemplar.

> [**ifRoom**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) : Sólo coloque este elemento en la barra de aplicaciones si hay
>   espacio para ello. Si no hay espacio para todos los elementos marcados
>   como "ifRoom", los elementos con los valores más bajos orderInCategory
>   se muestran como acciones y los elementos restantes se muestran en el
>   menú overflow.

Comment: el titulo si tiene un texto lo que yo lo tache, y como ves en la foto si hay sufisiente espacio para que se muestren 3 iconos mas que son los que tienen "ifRoom"

Answer (score 0):

se puede usar la función `setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)` sobre cada item del menú que quieras forzar su visibilidad.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Menu menuItems= toolbar.getMenu();
menuItems.findItem(R.id.action_share).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: si pero no me conviene forzar la visivilidad de los iconos siempre porque cundo el telefono este en vertical no hay espacio, lo que pregunto es porque si cuando pongo el telefono horizontal y hay espacio, como se ve en al foto,n o se muestran los icono con la propiedad ifRoom??

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón puedes detectar si está en vertical o en horizontal, obtener el total de pantalla, dividir por los iconos que podrían caber y determinas cuales de ellos debe ser visibles.

Comment: como obtendria el total de pantalla???

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón mira el siguiente enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-dimensiones-de-la-pantalla-en-android